# library not found for -lPods-Doppio-Mantle

Tags: ios, cocoapods, github-mantle

when build project,show this error,nothing to add in link binary with libraries,i don't know the reason

library not found for -lPods-Doppio-Mantle

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. What do your `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` look like? Have you tried cleaning your project and doing a fresh `pod install`?

Comment: Please, give us more information, copy the complete error trace.Tx

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were meaning after you install pod you have an error like that:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-Doppio
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Did you open the xworkspace that Cocoapods created, instead of xcodeproj?
Or check if you install pod in the right directory. I mean in the directory of your Project:

```
cd myProject
pod install
```